# real time voltage data plotting and logging

Tags: logging

I'm looking for a cost-effective fool-proof way to plot and log voltage over time. Ideally there would be a hardware&software solution to measure +/- 10v over a few hours. Unfortunately most software that comes with hardware seem to have very limited/archaic plotting capabilities. I would like to be able to zoom in and out of the time axis very easily.

Here's a list of software/hardware I've seen around along with my thoughts on it:

- PYQTGraph -http://www.pyqtgraph.org/ : seems powerful but hard to load data
- RRD Tool -oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/ :  Complicated...
- LabView -www.ni.com/labview/ : Expensive and overkill
- KST -kst-plot.kde.org : Seems good... but it's buggy and complicated
- arduino module -https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9147 - seems easy to log data, but no simple way to plot it.

And there are Hundreds of hardware/software packages like microdaq.com that i imagine would work fine... but i'm dubious of the plotting capabilities of the included software. Does anyone have experience doing this? The more simple and intuitive the better as most of the people using this will not have any experience coding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work in Test and Measurement and have the following advice:

1. Think of your logging needs as separate from your plotting needs. Pick a logger that can output data to a text file and don't worry about much else. I personally use LabVIEW and NI for this, but you should have any issues with someone like Microdaq.
2. Pick a plotting solution that's good at plotting text files. I personally use Matplotlib / Python, but can give more specific advice if needed (see link).
3. If you need real-time plotting the simplest solution is to create a "scheduled job" (task manager/Windows or cron/Linux) and run your script every few minutes or again I recommend something more complicated if needed.
4. On Stack Overflow open end questions like your's are generally not appreciated. I recommend trying to break it down into smaller pieces. Also, if you are looking for non-programming solutions this isn't the right place to do it.

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/plotfile_demo.html

Comment: Charlie, Thanks. I didn't fully realize that my question could have been interpreted as until you pointed it out... Much appreciated. I do need a real-time solution that doesn't have more than a few seconds of delay. I'll look into how to make scripts that run "scheduled jobs". Thanks!

Comment: I was want to view the plots in real time then you did to create a GUI. I would recommend using this as a starting point: http://newville.github.io/wxmplot/